Jackson serializing objects with circular reference
Is it possible to access or lookup annotation values that were placed on an object when using a custom serializer?

data class Parent(
  val name: String,
  @JsonIgnoreProperties("parent") 
  val child: Child
)
data class Child(
  val name: String,
  val parent: Parent,
)

class CustomSerializer : StdSerializer<Child>(Child::class.java) {
  override fun serialize(obj: Child, gen: JsonGenerator, provider: SerializerProvider) {
     gen.writeStartObject()
     gen.writeFieldName("name")
     gen.writeString(obj.name)
     // if i am serializing a child that is accessed from within a parent object
     // that should not be serialized because of @JsonIgnoreProperties
     // but if I am serializing a Child directly, the parent should be serialized
     gen.writeEndObject()
  }
}

